# launchd doesn't retrieve birthdays

Tags: bash, macos, automator, launchd

I've made an Automator app that finds people that has birthdays on a given day and saves the names of those in a text-file. It runs in a bash script that also alerts me when someone has a birthday. This works fine when i initiate the script from terminal. But when it runs through my ~/Library/LaunchAgents the birthday list is always empty. Does anybody have a clue, what could be the cause of this?

this is my agent-script

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>dk.emmajohnsen.birthdaygreetings</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>/bin/bash</string>
 <string>/Users/Emma/Projects/scripts/project_happy_birthday/orchestrateBirthdayAlert</string>
  </array>
  <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
  <dict>
    <key>Hour</key>
    <integer>08</integer>
    <key>Minute</key>
    <integer>17</integer>
  </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: It strongly depends on the contents of the associated launchctl.plist

Comment: @vadian it looks like this (put it in the question as it was too long to be allowed in a comment)

Comment: Is the plist loaded? Is the label listed when you run this in Terminal.app  `launchctl list | grep birthdaygreetings`

Comment: @vadian yep - and I can see from the logs that everything else that the `orchestrateBirthdayAlert` is supposed to do runs normally. It's only the Automator app that for some reason doesn't have access to the birthdays or something.

Comment: @vadian any ideas what else could be causing the difference?